# com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure\n

Tags: mysql, druid

Error Message:

> [{"businessNo":"af7df42$1***$2a71be7a6","errMsg":"\n### 
> Error querying database.  Cause: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.
> The program often: Communications link failure\n\nThe last packet successfully received from the server was 460,421 milliseconds ago. 
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 461,682 milliseconds ago.\n### 
> The error may exist in URL [jar:file:$1***$2]\n### 
> The error may involve defaultParameterMap\n### 
> The error occurred while setting parameters\n### SQL: select $1***$ = ?\n### 
> Cause: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure\n\n
> The last packet successfully received from the server was 460,421 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 461,682 milliseconds ago.\n; 
> Communications link failure\n\n
> The last packet successfully received from the server was 460,421 milliseconds ago. 
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 461,682 milliseconds ago.; nested exception is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure\n\n
> The last packet successfully received from the server was 460,421 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 461,682 milliseconds ago."}]

## Properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.type=com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource
spring.datasource.initialSize=10
spring.datasource.maxActive=200
spring.datasource.filters=stat
# obtain db connection timeout
spring.datasource.maxWait=60000
# check valid period for idle connections
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=9000
spring.datasource.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=300000
spring.datasource.validationQuery=select 1 from dual
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=false
spring.datasource.testOnReturn=false
spring.datasource.poolPreparedStatements=true
spring.datasource.maxPoolPreparedStatementPerConnectionSize=20
spring.datasource.removeAbandoned=true

Mysql timeout: 8 hour
```

## Version:

```
com.alibaba:druid 1.2.8
Mysql 5.7
```

## Code:

Our schedule task always throw this Exception:com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException  in method `callBackValidLeads()`, line : `List<CallBackLeadsEntity> callBackLeadsPos = callBackLeadsGateway.queryByIds(callBackIds);`

It takes about 10 minutes to finish this sechedule task. But the program often failed when `spring.datasource.testOnBorrow`  be set false.

```java
// DB query with Resulthandler
public RecordReportResultVo doCallBack(Long beginTime, Long endTime) {
    callBackLeadsGateway.queryCallBackList(beginTime, endTime, resultContext -> {
    callBackIds.add(resultContext.getResultObject());
        if (callBackIds.size() >= RECORD_SAVE_UNIT) {
            int successCount = callBackValidLeads(callBackIds, startTime);
            atomicInteger.addAndGet(successCount);
            callBackIds.clear();
        }
    });
}

    private int callBackValidLeads(List<Long> callBackIds, String startTime) {
        int successCount = 0;
        // DB query
        List<CallBackLeadsEntity> callBackLeadsPos = callBackLeadsGateway.queryByIds(callBackIds);
        for (CallBackLeadsEntity callBackLeadsPo : callBackLeadsPos) {
            // some code
            successCount += 1;
        }
        return successCount;
    }
```

We check the properties, when `spring.datasource.testOnBorrow` was set true, the program will be Ok